# Legacy assembly throws "Request for principal permission failed"

Tags: c#, .net, legacy, com+, code-access-security

I'm developing against some legacy .NET assemblies that are using System.EnterpriseServices and compiled in .NET Framework 2.0. I'm receiving a ***"Request for principal permission failed"*** exception in some scenarios but not in others. For example the code works OK when

- I run it from an xunit runner test in.net 4.5.1
- I runt it in as a webservice inside IIS also .net 4.5.1
- I run it from a windows forms application build against .net 2.0

But it throws an exception when I run it from a Windows forms app .net 4.5.1. In this case I get the mentioned exception and the FirstPermissionThatFailed.
    `<IPermission class="System.Security.Permissions.PrincipalPermission, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" version="1"><Identity Authenticated="true" Role="1,50000,50750,50751:Execute"/>
</IPermission>`

I reverse engineered the legacy API and saw that the functions have the following attribute
`[PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand,Role="1,50000,50750,50751:Execute")]`
I know that the problem is probably caused by major changes that were done to Code Access Security, but I do not know what exactly, so I have 2 questions:

1. To which actual roles do this roles id's map to 1,50000,50750,50751
2. Why is the code not triggering the exception when it is called from a resharper xunit test runner?? Like it is running in a different security context??

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding this to App.config solved the problem:

`<configuration>
  <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true" />
</configuration>`

I guess Resharper Xunit runner is using it when it loads and executes assemblies and that it's why it worked from tests.